# Android Save ArrayList<Integer> into local storage

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Hello what is best way to save ArrayList data on app exit and then retrieve it on app start. in my app i show some data to users and data is fetched from Url and i send a post request with already seen item to exclude that data but now this only works per session now i want it to save all ids in SharedPreferences so every time use request data they see unique data not matter if they exited app or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use https://github.com/kcochibili/TinyDB--Android-Shared-Preferences-Turbo

1). add [TinyDB.java](https://github.com/kcochibili/TinyDB--Android-Shared-Preferences-Turbo/blob/master/TinyDB.java) in your `module`

2). initialize TinyDB

```
TinyDB tinydb=new TinyDB(context);

// store Arraylist<Integer> list;
tinydb.putListInt("yourkey",list);

// retrive Arraylist<Integer>
Arraylist<Integer> list=tinydb.getListInt("yourkey");
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it is good to use SharedPreferences like below. You can use below example for it

```
public void saveArrayList(ArrayList<String> list, String key){
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(activity);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = gson.toJson(list);
        editor.putString(key, json);
        editor.apply();     // This line is IMPORTANT !!!
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getArrayList(String key){
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(activity);
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = prefs.getString(key, null);
        Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<String>>() {}.getType();
        return gson.fromJson(json, type);
    }
```

I just coppied this example from https://freakycoder.com/android-notes-40-how-to-save-and-get-arraylist-into-sharedpreference-7d1f044bc79a to explain process to you

Comment: i tried this but its replaces old data every time it saves but i need to push new data instead of replace